# Google ReCaptcha Request Details

Tags: python, ruby, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

Is it possible to get the details of ReCaptcha request in my Google Admin Console or is there any other way?

I am expecting it is possible to see the details of every reCaptcha requests or it is not possible to see the request details.

Answer (score 0):

The admin console shows you data on the requests, it doesn't provide you with any other real details about each request. It is possible to see the request details in other ways though. For example, you can print the response to the server log, eg

```
    secret_response = request.form.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    verify_response = requests.post(url=f'{VERIFY_URL}?secret={RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}&response={secret_response}').json()
    print(verify_response)
```

This will provide you with something like:

> {'success': True, 'challenge_ts': '2023-09-15T11:42:22Z', 'hostname': 'www.mysite.co.uk', 'score': 0.9}

You could email the response to your email address if you wanted to get a response when a request is made.

Comment: This is a separate response for backend validation of the g-recaptcha-response, but in Log Explorer I can find some logs. I could not determine they are the details of every request.